# How to Ignore Required Fields when updating user account details Django-Rest, ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, axios, image-upload

I have made a field for profile image in database:

**serializers.py**

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model=User
        fields=('id','username','email','password','first_name','last_name','profile_image')
```

**models.py**

I have made the following function for upload

```
    def upload_path(instance, pos, filname):
        return '/'.join(['profiles',  filname])
```

User Class

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, default='')
    

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, upload_to=objects.upload_path)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

**views.py**

My post method is:

```
def post(self, request):
        serializer = PostCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            items = Post.objects.all()
            serializer = PostCreateSerializer(items, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer 
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            serializer_class.save()
            queryset = User.objects.all()
            profile_image = request.data['profile_image']
            User.objects.create(queryset, profile_image=profile_image)
            return HttpResponse({'message':'profile image uploaded'}, status = 200) 
          
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

On my ReactJS frontend, I am doing the following:

I have made the following axios post method:

```
export const uploadProfile = (profile_image, id) => async (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ profile_image });
  alert("1234");
  console.log(body)
  try {
    await axios.post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}auth/users/`,
      body,
      config
    );
    console.log(Response);
    dispatch({
      type: UPLOAD_SUCCESS,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: UPLOAD_FAIL,
    });
  }
};
```

This is the form I am using it on:

```
const ChoosePhotoWidget = ({ title, photo, uploadProfile }) => {
  //   const [requestSent, setrequestSent] = useState(false);

  const [data, setdata] = useState({
    profile_image: "",
  });

  const onchangeEvent = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const name = event.target.name;

    setdata((preValue) => {
      return {
        ...preValue,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  };
  const { profile_image } = data;
  const onsubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    uploadProfile(profile_image);
    
  };
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onsubmit}>
      <Card border="light" className="bg-white shadow-sm mb-4">
        <Card.Body>
          <h5 className="mb-4">{title}</h5>
          <div className="d-xl-flex align-items-center">
            <div className="user-avatar xl-avatar">
              <Image fluid rounded src={profile_image} />
            </div>
            <div className="file-field">
              <div className="d-flex justify-content-xl-center ms-xl-3">
                <div className="d-flex">
                  <span className="icon icon-md">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperclip} className="me-3" />
                  </span>

                  {/* profile image */}
                  <div>
                    <input type="file" name='profile_image' onChange={onchangeEvent} />

                    <div className="d-md-block text-start">
                      <div className="fw-normal text-dark mb-1">
                        Choose Image
                      </div>
                      <div className="text-gray small">
                        JPG, GIF or PNG. Max size of 800K
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <p></p>
                        <Button variant="tertiary text-white" type="submit">
                          Change
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Form>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  pagestate: state.auth.pagestate,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { uploadProfile })(ChoosePhotoWidget);
```

[It obviously gives me required fields error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75dTU.png)

Is there any way where I can post current values for required fields. Or would that register a new user instead? I have no ideas on how to do it without making another table for profile images in my database.